# iOS Game Center unable to send match data with NSCoding

Tags: ios, game-center

So right now I'm working on sending the match data in a turn based game and I was using this post as a reference.
[Good practices for Game Center matchData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104041/good-practices-for-game-center-matchdata)

I created a new class and it implements NSCoding. It currently only holds one variable for a NSString. This is the code for when I send the match data.

```
self.game.status = @"Test";

NSData *updatedMatchData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.game];

[self.currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextPerson]
                                     turnTimeout:1000
                                       matchData:updatedMatchData
                               completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                 if (error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                 }
                               }];
  NSLog(@"Successfully ended turn");
}
```

When I try retrieving the match data, I tried this.

```
[match loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error) {
    if (matchData)
    {
      RaceGame *updatedGame = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];

      NSLog(@"Match Data: %@", updatedGame.status); //prints null
      callback(matchData); 
    }
  }];
```

However, status is null. I've checked that match isn't null either. I also printed out the match and it said that matchData.length = 135, but I kept changing things around and it was still 135 so I'm not sure if that's helpful.

Any ideas on why status isn't changing?

**--EDIT--**

.m

```
@implementation RaceGame

@synthesize status;

#pragma mark - NSCoding protocol

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
   [aCoder encodeObject:status forKey:@"status"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.status = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"status"];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

.h

```
@interface RaceGame : NSObject <NSCoding> {
  NSString *status;
}

/* Match Data */
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *status;

@end
```

Comment: Maybe the answer lies in your `NSCoding` protocol implementation. Could you post that (for the `RaceGame` class)?

Comment: Sure, it's posted. They're pretty much identical to the example in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, really stupid mistake by me. I was testing it on two devices and I only ran the updated version on one of the devices.